# How to install JQuery UI and animate a divs color?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am currently using jQuery to animate the position of a div

```
import $ from "jquery";

$("#divId").animate({
    left: "50px"
}, 1000);
```

Which works correctly. Now, I would like to animate the color of the div as well. Something like:

```
$("#divId").animate({
    left: "50px",
    backgroundColor: "green"
}, 1000);
```

To do this, I tried to use the jQuery-UI library and import it as follows:

```
import $ from "jquery";
import "jqueryui";
```

However, nothing seems to happen. I have looked at the jQuery-UI documentation and cannot seem to find the documentation for importing the library into a project with this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Tested and your code works as expected.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#divId").animate({
    left: "50px",
    backgroundColor: "green"
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
#divId {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="divId"></div>
```

Check your Console for Errors and confirm in the View Source that you're loading all the expected libraries.